# Use pluralization with nested keyword messages

Tags: php, yaml, translation, symfony4

Im using the translation component in symfony 4.0 with the YAML loader. According to [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html#creating-translations) im able to nest my messages in keys like this:

```
msg:
    foo: baz
    bar: qux
```

Which is working fine when I'm retrieving the values with:

```
$translator->trans(
    'msg.foo'
);
```

What I'm struggling with is adding pluralization to the mix - Take for example:

```
$translator->transChoice(
    'msg.singular|msg.plural',
    2
);
```

This on its own outputs either `msg.singular` or as in this case `msg.plural` as expected, and it consumes messages when I define them like:

```
msg.singular|msg.plural: There is one Apple|There are %count% Apples
```

What it won't accept is any of the following:

```
msg:
    singular: There is one Apple
    plural: There are %count% Apples

# or

msg:
    singular|plural: There is one Apple|There are %count% Apples
```

Which makes sense, since it would get flattened to:

```
msg.singular: There is one Apple
msg.plural: There are %count% Apples

# or

msg.singular|plural: There is one Apple|There are %count% Apples
```

My question is: How am I able to use the pluralization features symfony provides while leveraging nested keys for my translation data?